# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The SQL below results in the Oracle 11g error: `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRINT'`. But it looks to me like my `print` procedure expects 1 varchar2 argument and that it's exactly what I am passing to it as an argument.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (full_name VARCHAR2(64))
//

INSERT INTO employees (full_name) VALUES ('John')
//

INSERT INTO employees (full_name) VALUES ('Paul')
//

INSERT INTO employees (full_name) VALUES ('George')
//

INSERT INTO employees (full_name) VALUES ('Ringo')
//

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print (
  v_string IN VARCHAR2
) IS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(v_string);
END print;
//

DECLARE
  v_string VARCHAR2(64);
BEGIN
    FOR v_string IN (SELECT DISTINCT full_name
                            FROM  employees) LOOP
        print (v_string);
    END LOOP;
END;
//
```

I can reproduce the issue in SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0e80e/6

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: I think part of the problem is that your record name `v_string` is misleading, because glancing at the `print()` call in the loop it looks as though you are passing a string. I always use `r` for a cursor loop record unless there is some good reason to use something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, you've done it wrong. Should've been

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2      FOR v_string IN (SELECT DISTINCT full_name
  3                              FROM  employees) LOOP
  4          p_print (v_string.full_name);
  5      END LOOP;
  6  END;
  7  /
John
Paul
George
Ringo

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Why? Because you declared local variable and used cursor `FOR` loop (whose record shares the same name with the local variable). What you passed to `print` procedure was a cursor variable, not a local variable.

As [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155) says:

> The cursor FOR LOOP statement implicitly declares its loop index as a record variable of the row type that a specified cursor returns, and then opens a cursor.

Syntax is: `for record in ...`, where `record` represents

> name for the loop index that the cursor FOR LOOP statement implicitly declares as a %ROWTYPE record variable of the type that cursor or select_statement returns.

Comment: I didn't initially see the difference between your answer and my original code so in case others don't see it either, note that the procedure call is ```print (v_string.full_name)``` not ```print (v_string)```. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0e80e/8

Comment: Right, you found the difference, well done :)